# Where can I find database tuning exercises for learning?

Tags: sql-server, database-tuning

As a developer, often DBAs take responsibility for resolving performance issues at the database level so we don't get that much experience diagnosing, tuning, refactoring queries etc.

I'm looking for a database with a bunch of tables, data, queries, triggers, SPs and so on, in which there are deliberate performance problems, and hopefully a series of exercises in which you attempt to identify and resolve the problems. Ideally this will be on MS SQL server.

Anyone know of this kind of thing?

Answer (score 15):

Paul Randal provides some sample DBs that are actually corrupt: http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Conference-corruption-demo-scripts-and-example-corrupt-databases.aspx

Good exercise to go through working with DBCC commands and such on SQL Server.

Answer (score 8):

If you're a developer and you have a DBA team I strongly suggest you look into booking some time with them to go over tuning.
As a DBA (who does dev and architecture too!) supporting thousands of users I can honestly say that I will *always* make time to meet with developers that are serious about learning how to improve their SQL skills. An email here or there is ok but it takes a lot of time to properly explain things in an email and it takes time away from my more important duties. Scheduling a meeting to discuss tips or techniques or even go over issues live works out great! I can share tips on tools, scripts, how to spot problems, good designs vs. bad designs, etc.

Specific to your question - I'm not aware of any training database like that but it does sounds like a good opportunity for the community!