# How can I benchmark the performance of UDFs to figure out which one is faster?

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, benchmark

Basically I have two scalar UDFs that output the same data, one that uses a cursor and one that uses a recursive CTE. I want to determine which one should be used and discard the other; I'd prefer to make this decision based on actual performance numbers. I'm also curious *how much* of a difference there is between the two.

How can I benchmark the performance of these UDFs to figure out which one is faster?

Comment: 'Good/Best' are considered to be subjective questions, that is why I re-framed your question.

Comment: In this particular case, its not about the UDF; whether CTE or Cursor causing the performance. You are free to post both UDF's definition here, so that experts can look at it and suggest work arounds.

Comment: @Sandy, posting the udf definitions sounds like it would lead to qualitative analysis, which is *definitely not* what I'm asking for. I want to base this decision on the cold hard truth of raw performance numbers *only*.

Answer (score 7):

The SQL Profiler, execution plan, IO/Cpu statistics are your best friend at checking the performance of your code. You will see if there are any differences in performance between the 2 versions of functions.

In this question - [Tuning exercises](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/648/where-can-i-find-database-tuning-exercises-for-learning) - you can find some basic and advanced references about tuning.